# How do I pass my initialized GraphQL handler to multiple AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql

I have a GraphQL server that is using AWS Lambdas. I am trying to create type resolvers for many of my domain objects. With each one of these Lambdas, I have to initialize all of my handlers to fulfill the logic for the resolver. Here is an example.

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { Project } from 'graphql/appsync';
import { initializeHandlers } from 'lambdas/graphql/initializer';
import { Event } from 'lib/resolvers/types';

export const card: Handler<Event<Project>> = async (event) => {
  const handlers = await initializeHandlers();

  if (event.source.cardId) {
    return await handlers.card.getCard(
      event.identity.claims.sub,
      event.source.customerId,
      event.source.cardId
    );
  }

  throw new Error('no card id');
};
```

The `initializeHandlers` function is expensive. I am having to do this in each Lambda. Is there a way to do it once and pass it to the handler via context or some other manner?

The resolver are being created using a `NodejsFunction`. I am hoping I can pass the initialized handler through that function somehow.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I took this very approach (one Lambda per entity) one time and regretted it deeply. What happened is I'd hit cold starts for each nested object and had to hack keeping everything warm all the time. What worked much better was having one monolithic-style Lambda as an entrypoint. It resolves many other problems other than just cold starts such as cost and the problem you're trying to solve now.

Comment: That is what we have for our main entry points, but I am trying to figure out how to create type resolvers. The only way I could find a way to do this was creating other lambdas, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (necessary in each Lambda though) would be to initialize the handler object otuside of the function given that it is agnostic to the invoked function's context.

Then that statement would be executed during the init phase (as are the imports).
Subsequently, you may add [provisionedConcurrecy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html) of say 1 to have a warm Lambda function at all points in time that has completed initialization of the environment.